# How to iterate over the arrayList of objects in the java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring, spring-boot

I have used angular to send the array of objects to Api for post operation which is going with Arrays of 3 Objects:

[image]
I wanted this in java so i initialized class in java as:

> **`SLDto.java`**

```
 public class SLDto {

        private LetterDto letterDto;
        private List<DocumentDto> documentDto;
        private List<SelectionCustomOfficeDto> selectionCustomOfficeDto;



        public SLDto() {

        }
//i omitted getters and setters here
    }
```

> **`LetterDto.java`**

```
public class LetterDto {

  private int clkletter;
 private String inOut;
 private String inOutNo;
private String inOutDate;
private String letterIssuedSubBy;
private String letterFile;
private String representativeName;
private int assessmentNo;
private int selectionNo;


public LetterDto() {

}
```

> **`DocumentDto.java`**

```
public class DocumentDto {

    private int docId;
    private String docName;
    private boolean checked;

    public DocumentDto() {

    }
}
```

> **`SelectionCustomOfficeDto.java`**

```
public class SelectionCustomOfficeDto {

 private int id;
 private String fromDate;
 private String  toDate;
 private int consignmentNo;
 private int selectionId;
 private int customOfficeId;
 private String custOfficeName;
 private String selectionName;
}
```

i need to map the Client side Objects to Api so i used the method :

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/letter/create")
        public String postAllOne(@RequestBody SLDto sldto ) {

            //i tried 2ways to see the json data or trace it and assign into 
         respective objects but i am not getting.I tried
        1st method
       System.out.println(sldto.getLetterDto()); //Not working 

       2nd method 
         for(LetterDto letterDto:sldto.getLetterDto()) {
                //it is not allowing me
            }

            return  "success";
        }
```

it is not allowing me to map as:

[image]

How can i separate the 3json data into their respective Object?

```
[{"inOutNo":"2018-11-12","inOutDate":"2","inOut":"AnnexOne","letterFile":null,"representativeName":null,"assessmentNo":0,"letterIssuedSubBy":null,"selectionNo":8},[{"docId":1,"docName":"proforma invoice","checked":true},{"docId":2,"docName":"Packing list","checked":true}],[{"customOfficeId":"1","fromDate":"2018-11-12","toDate":"2018-11-20","consignmentNo":2,"selectionId":8,"selectionName":"PCS","custOfficeName":"Bhairawa Bhansar"}]]
```

The error seen is

I am getting error like

> "DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
>   com.ashwin.springsecurityangular.dto.SLDto out of START_ARRAY token;
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of com.ashwin.springsecurityangular.dto.SLDto out
>   of START_ARRAY token"

Comment: as per your class defination `letterDto` is not a `collection` nor an `array`. is it a typo?

Comment: I am getting error like "DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.ashwin.springsecurityangular.dto.SLDto` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.ashwin.springsecurityangular.dto.SLDto` out of START_ARRAY token"

Comment: Ok - there seem to compile time error in your post and hence the question was.

Comment: can you post input json

Comment: i have posted a image at beginning of page please see it

Comment: That's hard to follow. you can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(yourobj))` .

Comment: @secretsuperstar, `console.log()` is for javascript. OP has tagged and written the programs using JAVA..

Comment: I thought  the first screenshot taken from web browser

Comment: i have edited my post please see json data i have posted just now

Comment: @ashwinkarki, try to post code and errors as text rather than images as it would be easier for others to copy the code and reproduce the error and fix it.

Comment: The first problem is you are sending `jsonarray` but you mapping to single pojo. Are you using jackson for mapping?

Comment: yes brother i have used jackson how can i handle this problem? its 6hour i am getting in this problem :(

Comment: ok @Rai what codes do u need more please can u tell me?

Comment: you are currently recieveing a single `Letter` object in the body, you map it to a `LetterDTO` and you want to iterate over it, but object is not a list, if you want to iterate over `Documents` or `SelectionCustomOfficeDto ` you should do a `for` over `sldto:getDocumentDTO`, `sldto:getSelectionCustomOfficeDto `respectively

Comment: also, I would recommend formatting the body as an Object (`{ "letter": "...", "documentDto": [{...}, {...}], "selectionCustomOfficeDto": [{...},{...}]}`)

Comment: send as json object. Posting an example

Comment: formating the body means what should i need to do @Brad

Comment: I think you need to consider to edit the post subject. it does not relevant to the issue you are facing

Comment: @Rai i need to learn something about posting on stackoverflow.How to bring the "error code" in red block and highlighting the ".java" class?You have edited my post and I find it awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send like `json` like below:

```
 {
    "letterDto" : {"clkletter": "as" }, // your other properties,
    "documentDto": [{"docId" : 1},{"docId" : 2}]// your other properties inside json object
    "selectionCustomOfficeDto": [{"id": 12},{"id": 121}]// your other properties inside json object

 }
```

The below is example for your reference, The `outer` class has `List<Inner2>`, `List<Inner3>` and `Inner1`

The `Json` would looks like

```
{
    "inner1": {"f1": "v1","f2": "v2"},
    "inner2s": [{"f3": "v3","f4": "v4"},{"f3": "v5","f4": "v6"}],

    "inner3s": [{"f5": "v7","f6": "v8"},{"f5": "v9","f6": "v10"}]
}
```

PoJo classes

```
class Outer{
        Inner1 inner1;
        List<Inner2> inner2s;
        List<Inner3> inner3s;

        public Inner1 getInner1() {
            return inner1;
        }
        public void setInner1(Inner1 inner1) {
            this.inner1 = inner1;
        }
        public List<Inner2> getInner2s() {
            return inner2s;
        }
        public void setInner2s(List<Inner2> inner2s) {
            this.inner2s = inner2s;
        }
        public List<Inner3> getInner3s() {
            return inner3s;
        }
        public void setInner3s(List<Inner3> inner3s) {
            this.inner3s = inner3s;
        }

    }

     class Inner1{

        String f1;
        String f2;
        public String getF1() {
            return f1;
        }
        public void setF1(String f1) {
            this.f1 = f1;
        }
        public String getF2() {
            return f2;
        }
        public void setF2(String f2) {
            this.f2 = f2;
        }



    }
     class Inner2{
        String f3;
        String f4;
        public String getF3() {
            return f3;
        }
        public void setF3(String f3) {
            this.f3 = f3;
        }
        public String getF4() {
            return f4;
        }
        public void setF4(String f4) {
            this.f4 = f4;
        }


    }

     class Inner3{
        String f5;
        String f6;
        public String getF5() {
            return f5;
        }
        public void setF5(String f5) {
            this.f5 = f5;
        }
        public String getF6() {
            return f6;
        }
        public void setF6(String f6) {
            this.f6 = f6;
        }


    }
```

The request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,method= {RequestMethod.POST})
    public String post(@RequestBody Outer outer) {
        LOGGER.debug("Getting the logged in cutomer details" +outer);
        Customer customer1 = new Customer("1", "customer1", "Sample@cust1.com");
        LOGGER.info("The customer details are " + customer1);
        return "done!!";
    }
```

Comment: Please reason for downvote, so, if something wrong, that can be learnt. Thanks

Comment: I made my array to looki like this :

Comment: sorry - I could not follow you

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: thnks for too much effort @secret super star you did a too much help for me today

Answer (score 1):

Your current `POST` method handler expects a JSON object of the following format:

```
{
    "letterDto" : {
        "clkletter" : 1, 
        "inOut" : "Someting",
        ...
    },
    "documentDto" : [
        {
            "docId" : 1,
            "docName" : "Name",
            "checked" : true
        } ,
        {
            "docId" : 2,
            "docName" : "Name 2",
            "checked" : false
        }
    ],
    "selectionCustomOfficeDto" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "fromDate" : "someDate,
            ...
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "fromDate" : "someDate2,
            ...
        }
    ]

}
```

But currently, you are sending a JSON array:

```
[
    "letterDto" : {<letter properties>},
    [
        {
            <document properties>
        },
        {
            <document properties>
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            <selection custom office properties>
        }
    ]
]
```

After fixing this, you will be able to iterate over `slDto.getDocumentDto` and `slDto.getSelectionCustomOfficeDto` as those are the only **collections** contained in the `slDto` object, so:

```
slDto.getSelectionCustomOfficeDto.forEach(s -> doSomething(s));

slDto.getDocumentDto.forEach(d -> doSomething(d));
```

And you can call the `Letter`'s methods like this:

```
slDto.getLetterDto.getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi please make sure your JSON request looks like this :

```
{
    "letterDto" : {
        "clkletter" : 1,
        "inOut" : "some-string-value",
        "inOutNo" : "some-string-value",
        "inOutDate" : "some-string-value",
        "letterIssuedSubBy" : "some-string-value",
        "letterFile" : "some-string-value",
        "representativeName" : "some-string-value",
        "assessmentNo" : 1,
        "selectionNo" : 1
    },
    "documentDto" : [
        {
            "docId" : 1,
            "docName" : "some-doc-name",
            "checked" : true
        },
        {
            "docId" : 2,
            "docName" : "some-doc-name",
            "checked" : true
        },
        {
            "docId" : 3,
            "docName" : "some-doc-name",
            "checked" : true
        }
    ],
    "selectionCustomOfficeDto" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "fromDate" : "some-date",
            "toDate" : "some-date",
            "consignmentNo" : 1,
            "selectionId" : 1,
            "customOfficeId" : 1,
            "custOfficeName" : "some-office-name",
            "selectionName" : "some-selection-name"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "fromDate" : "some-date",
            "toDate" : "some-date",
            "consignmentNo" : 1,
            "selectionId" : 1,
            "customOfficeId" : 1,
            "custOfficeName" : "some-office-name",
            "selectionName" : "some-selection-name"
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "fromDate" : "some-date",
            "toDate" : "some-date",
            "consignmentNo" : 1,
            "selectionId" : 1,
            "customOfficeId" : 1,
            "custOfficeName" : "some-office-name",
            "selectionName" : "some-selection-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, in the code block,

```
for(LetterDto letterDto:sldto.getLetterDto()) {
//it is not allowing me
}
```

Here `sldto.getLetterDto()` return a single `LetterDto` `Object` instead of a `List`, so iteration is not possible.

Hope it helps!